# How to check Collections.insert() is Successfully Inserted or not in Meteor?

Tags: collections, meteor

How to check(user created collections) Collections.insert() is Successfully Inserted or not in `Meteor JS`?. For example I am using the Client Collections to insert details as shown below:

```
Client.insert({ name: "xyz", userid: "1", care:"health" });
```

How to know the above insert query is successfully inserted or not?. Because of the below problem

```
 If the form details are successfully inserted  - do one action
  else -another action
```

So Please suggest me what to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Insert provides a server response in the arguments to a callback function. It provides two arguments 'error' and 'result' but one of them will always be null depending on whether the insert is successful.

```
Client.insert( { name: "xyz", userid: "1", care:"health" }
  , function( error, result) { 
    if ( error ) console.log ( error ); //info about what went wrong
    if ( result ) console.log ( result ); //the _id of new object if successful
  }
);
```

See [documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#insert) for more info.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to user728291's answer that uses a callback, on the server, you can also do:

`var value = Collection.insert({foo: bar});`

which will return the `_id` of the inserted record on success (executions is blocked until the db acknowledges the write). You will have to handle a possible error in a `try...catch`, but sometimes callbacks are just a bit, cumbersome :)

So this should also work on the server:

```
try {
    var inserted = Collection.insert({foo: bar});
} 
catch (error) {
    console.log("Could not insert due to " + error);
}

if (inserted)
    console.log("The inserted record has _id: " + inserted);
```

Thank you @user728291 for the clarification.

Comment: I am not sure this is correct.  From the docs - "On the server, if you don't provide a callback, then insert blocks until the database acknowledges the write, or throws an exception if something went wrong." And "On the client, insert never blocks. If you do not provide a callback and the insert fails on the server, then Meteor will log a warning to the console."

Comment: @user728291 That sounds correct. And explains some of the things I've seen happening in my code ... I'll update the answer, thanks

Comment: On the server I think you would want to use try and catch to avoid the error being thrown.  The 'else' portion would never trigger.

Comment: You are once again correct user728291. Should probably not have answered :)

Comment: This answer is correct if you want to do it synchronously.

Comment: Hmm is it still asynchronous, since Meteor wraps calls into fibers?