# Not getting callback after insert

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor

I am not really sure why I am not getting the callback from the server after `Collection.insert`. I have been referring to [this stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21672155/how-to-check-collections-insert-is-successfully-inserted-or-not-in-meteor), but I cannot seem to figure out how to get the callback of a successful or errored insert.

**Server.js**

```
Meteor.startup(function () {

  // Using matb33:collection-hooks, this will record a timestamp before
  // each resonance is created     
  Resonance.before.insert(function(userId, doc){
      doc.createdAt = new Date();
  })

  if (Resonance.find().count() === 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < resonance.length; i++)
      Resonance.insert({ email: resonance[i].email }, function(error, result) {
        if (error) console.log ('there was an error!');
        if (result) console.log ('Success!!!');
      });
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm curious, what is `Resonance.before.insert`? I don't see that in the documentation.

Comment: @ChristianFritz See https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks

Comment: Austin, there must be more to the story, as I'm not seeing anything critically wrong with your code. Would you please include the definition of 'resonance'? Double check that the collection is indeed empty? Run 'meteor reset' and confirm again.

Comment: It works in Meteorpad. Here's a working example. I just used the `Players` collection as the name, using their sample app as a starting point. http://meteorpad.com/pad/kmi9wtA5yZqx2TF4c/Leaderboard